# SQL Connection Error to Remote Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have an application in C# to pull data down off a remote hosted server (winhost) to sync up to a local sql server (replication not an option) ... Very small data sets 10-100 for testing I am only retrieving 2 rows.  The application works fine on my Development machine.  However on the client network I get an intermittent error say half the time:

```
Error Occurred Getting Record From Remote Server: Details =>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): 
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection  to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is  correct and that SQL Server 
is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error:  26 - Error Locating 
Server/Instance Specified) at  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, 
Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()     At 
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,  SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, 
Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean  trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo  serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout,  SqlConnection owningObject) at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo,  String newPassword, 
Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString  connectionOptions, 
TimeoutTimer timeout) at  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection 
owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String  newPassword, Boolean redirectedUser
Instance) at  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity,  SqlConnectionString 
connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection  owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions  options, Object 
poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) at  System.Data.ProviderBase.
DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection,  DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) 
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection  owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection  owningConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, 
DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()  at 
System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode) at    AfocImport.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

On my Development machine I have 20 mb/s down and the app works no problem never encountered this error, however client is T1 1.5mb/s down.  I'm assuming this is the issue however it could also be something on the clients network ( firewall I checked ) ...

So my question is is this error solely indicative of connection timeout, or could it be something else ?  If it is, is there anything I can do to rectify the situation (unfortunately this is the only internet available to the client).  I tried messing around with the Connection Timeout but this didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does a ping/tracert look like? How about trying to connect to the remote server using telnet on port 1433? My guess is that either the port is blocked or DNS is not resolving. Are you trying to connect to the remote server by name? Did you try IP address?

Comment: Using the IP instead of the server name seems to help however I think the terribly slow internet connection is really the culprit ... If I don't use encryption it seems to work fine tho ... Thanks For the input, ima have to send you a Christmas card at this rate

Comment: If that's the case they may have to decide between encryption / performance / upgrading their connectivity. When you say "only Internet available" are they on an island or a remote area with only one choice? In most areas there are usually better alternatives, and the reluctance is more about the money (but I do understand there *are* cases where there really are no choices).

Comment: No its funny its in Manhattan which you would think would be no problem.  However one of the common problems I have  here is that companies like Verizon, Time Warner don't wire every building they want the buildings to pay for wiring so you'll be in one building with blazing fast business fios and right next store your stuck with running T1 or DSL ... Verizon has effectively stopped running fiber optic in Manhattan due to the cost and the company is trying to persuade time warner to run in a cable line but right now its looking bleak ...